# Trouble setting up Nagios to monitor Oracle services

Tags: oracle

I've got an install of Nagios XI that doesn't seem to want to talk to any of my Oracle services here. I've pulled out the monitoring command and am running it manually, after setting `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBDRARY_PATH` of course, but it keeps generating the following error:

```
/usr/local/nagios # libexec/check_oracle_health --connect "oracle-server:1551" --username user --password "pass" --name OFFDB1 --mode tablespace-can-allocate-next --warning 20 --critical 30
CRITICAL - cannot connect to oracle-server:1551. ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)
```

I'm still fairly new to Oracle, but my googlings seem to indicate that `SERVICE_NAME` should match the `GLOBAL_DBNAME` in `listener.ora`, which is OFFDB1. Do I need to do something else here like modify the connect string?

As a note, there are multiple instances of oracle sharing the target box, but each seems to be intalled to separate partitions and are running their own listeners or various ports.

Comment: Does `libexec/check_oracle_health --connect=OFFDB1 --mode=tnsping` work? If not, you need a correctly configured `tnsnames.ora` on the nagios box.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I have one at all, but I think I may have found one I can use. It is just supposed to live in `$ORACLE_HOME`?

Comment: $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Comment: The only folders I have in `$ORACLE_HOME` are `bin` and `lib`. I've created `network/admin` and copied tnsnames.ora from the database server, but now I just get a `CRITICAL - cannot connect to OFFDB1. ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)`. I'm getting the feeling that this `network` folder should have already existed.

Comment: If you are using Oracle Instant Client the default location of tnsnames.ora is /etc/tnsnames.ora, still in most cases you will get away with an EZConnect string as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil mentioned, I created `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` and `tnsnames.ora`.  I have something like this:

```
OFFDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle-server)(PORT = 1551))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = OFFDB1)
    )
  )
```

I then modified the monitoring commands:

```
/usr/local/nagios# libexec/check_oracle_health --connect=OFFDB1 --username user 
    --password "pass" --mode tablespace-can-allocate-next --warning 20 --critical 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the newer EZConnect format: `host:port/service:connection_type` saving you the hassle of adding a TNS entry.

The `connection_type` and `port` are both optional and will default to `dedicated` and `1521` respectively.

Changing the connect parameter of your monitoring command as follows should do the trick:

```
--connect "oracle-server:1551/OFFDB1"
```